# Saving dynamic custom checkout fields in Woo commerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new to PHP and I ordinarily search the net for articles and tutorials when I have a coding issue. Unfortunately I have been searching for a couple of days while trying my own fixes without luck, so I hope someone can help.

I am building a site with Wordpress and Woo commerce. I have followed some tutorials like this (http://www.portmanteaudesigns.com/blog/2015/02/04/woocommerce-custom-checkout-fields-email-backend/) to add custom fields to the woo commerce checkout.

I need to add a field to the checkout for every item in the cart, so that information can be collected per item (so if quantity of items in the cart is 6, there will be 6 fields for information to be provided).

Using the below code, for every item in the cart, a field is added:

```
/**
 * Add the field to the checkout
 **/
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'wordimpress_custom_checkout_field' );

function wordimpress_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

 //Check if Shoe in Cart (UPDATE WITH YOUR PRODUCT ID)
 $shoe_in_cart = wordimpress_is_conditional_product_in_cart();

 //Shoe is in cart so show additional fields
 if ( $shoe_in_cart === true ) {
 echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field">';

 foreach ($_SESSION['value'] as $key => $value) {
    $n = 1;
    $itemQuantity = $value['quantity'];
    $ProductID = $value['product_id'];
    $_product = $value['data']->post;


        for($QuantityCheck = 0; $QuantityCheck < $itemQuantity; $QuantityCheck++) {
            $LabelTitle = ($_product->post_title. ' '.$n.' - shoe name');
            woocommerce_form_field( 'inscription_textbox'.$ProductID.$n, array(
                'type'  => 'text',
                'required'  => true,    
                'placeholder'   => __('Shoe name'),     
                'class' => array( 'inscription-text form-row-wide' ),
                'label' => __( $LabelTitle ),
                ), $checkout->get_value( 'inscription_textbox'.$ProductID.$n ) );
            $checkoutFieldName = ('inscription_textbox'.$ProductID.$n);
            $_SESSION['checkoutFields'] [] = $checkoutFieldName;
            $n ++;
        }

 }

 echo '</div>';

}
}
```

I tried to attach a picture of the result but my reputation isn't high enough (the code works and the dynamic additional fields are added).

My problem lies in saving these dynamic custom fields to the database or make them show on the order confirmation page.

This is the latest code I used to try and save the field information to the database:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {

    foreach($_SESSION['checkoutFields'] as $key => $value){
    if( isset($_POST[$value]) ) {
        add_post_meta($order_id, $value, $_POST[$value]);
    }
}

}
```

Please help.

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: I am having the exact same issue.

Comment: @Brock I still haven't been able to find a solution, if I do I will share here.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since the question was posted, but I am sure this can help others so let me answer on how to do it.

This is what you're doing:

```
function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {

foreach($_SESSION['checkoutFields'] as $key => $value){
if( isset($_POST[$value]) ) {
    add_post_meta($order_id, $value, $_POST[$value]);
}}}
```

But guess what? You don't have to do that. You don't even need to use `foreach` WordPress have a core function called `maybe_serialize` Which automatically checks whether the value is an array.

So you would do it like this:

```
function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {    
    if( isset($_POST[$value]) ) {
        add_post_meta($order_id, $value, $_POST[$value]);
    }}
```

[Here is](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/243238/how-to-update-post-meta-value-as-array) another amazing answer that describes the answer in great details.